# EF Core: One-to-one and One-to-many Relationships Between a Single Pair of Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Below is a simplified representation of some entities that I wish to access using an EF Core model. A `Company` can have an optional one-to-one relationship with its `Manager`, as well as a one-to-many relationship with its `Employee`s.

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual Manager Manager {  get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId {  get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company {  get; set; }
    public int CompanyId {  get; set; }
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
}
```

The entities are exposed to EF Core in the usual way:

```
public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

I have attempted to model their relationships, as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(item => item.Employees)
    .WithOne(item => item.Company)
    .HasForeignKey(item => item.CompanyId)
    .IsRequired(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>()
    .HasOne(item => item.Company)
    .WithOne(item => item.Manager)
    .HasForeignKey<Company>(item => item.ManagerId)
    .IsRequired(false);
```

However, at runtime, EF Core rejects this configuration with the message "*Cannot create a relationship between 'Company.Manager' and 'Employee.Company' because a relationship already exists between 'Company.Employees' and 'Employee.Company'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Employee.Company' first in 'OnModelCreating'.*"

Can anyone suggest how to configure this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extending an existing concrete entity with an other one, the extending's class fields are added on the same table, so that in  a single row you can determine which employee is also a manager. This is called Table Per Hierarchy (TPH).

What you would like is a pattern of Table Per Type (TPT) - not yet provided by entity out of the box. More about those [here!](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance)

To set it up yourself until then, define the models "totaly by fluent api", such that you create your own relations without needed to use entity conventions.

Something like so ( not even build though, its a notepad doodle )

```
public class Employee {
    public string EmployeeId {get;set;}
    public string DisplayName {get;set;}

    public string WorksAtCompanyId {get;set;}
    public Company WorksAtCompany {get;set; }

    public string ManagesCompanyId {get;set;}
    public Company ManagesCompany {get;set; }

}

modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
b.Property<string>("EmployeeId").HasMaxLength(36).HasColumnType("nvarchar(36)");
b.Property<string>("DisplayName").HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
b.Property<string>("WorksAtCompanyId").HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
b.Property<string>("ManagesCompanyId").HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

b.HasOne(d => d.WorksAtCompany).WithMany(d => d.Employees).HasPrincipalKey<Employee>(d => d.WorksAtCompanyId).HasForeignKey<Company>(d => d.CompanyId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
b.HasOne<Company>(d => d.ManagesCompany).WithOne<Employee>(d => d.Manager).HasPrincipalKey<Employee>(d => d.ManagesCompanyId).HasForeignKey<Company>(d => d.CompanyId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


public class Company {
    public string CompanyId {get;set;}
    public List<Employee> Employees {get;set;}

    public string ManagerId {get;set;}
    public Employee Manager {get;set;}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
b.Property<string>("CompanyId").HasMaxLength(36).HasColumnType("nvarchar(36)");
b.Property<string>("DisplayName").HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

b.HasMany(d => d.Employees).WithOne<Employee>(d => d.WorksAtCompany).HasPrincipalKey<Employee>(d => d.WorksAtCompanyId).HasForeignKey<Company>(d => d.CompanyId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
b.HasOne(d => d.Manager).WithOne(d => d.ManagesCompany).HasPrincipalKey<Employee>(d => d.ManagesCompanyId).HasForeignKey<Company>(d => d.CompanyId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I am converting an existing EF6 app to use EF Core, and I am not able to modify the database schema. Under EF6, these relationships worked fine, using TPH, and without the need to define any fluent configuration. Are you saying that this is not possible using EF Core?

Comment: Based on this link, i only add the following:
The table-per-type (TPT) feature was introduced in EF Core 5.0. Table-per-concrete-type (TPC) is supported by EF6, but is not yet supported by EF Core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: The database schema does not need to change, you just need to understand the fluent api configuration and explicitly define each column's relation to foreign keys, from seperated classes ( even on the same table ) so that when querying, you map the results to the same semantic concepts. Its not very intuitive, i remember i had a bit of trial and error, just tweak, produce migration script and look it up and you can mostly deduce the fault and next tweak, even running the schema a couple of times until its the needed one, on a separated local db. After the schema is identical

Comment: you can have the app startup, verify the migration schema is already run from the migration history ( insert it yourself ) and let it run

Comment: By "ecplitycly" i mean not only the hasOne, hasMany, but the principal and foreign parts, that you dont want the ef core framework to deduce on its own

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions. In the end, I got it working just by creating a dummy navigation property ManagedCompany on my Manager class, and using this as the target for the relationship between Manager and Company. It's essentially the same concept that you have proposed with the 2 navigation properties in your Employee class, but I didn't need to make any big changes to my fluent model configuration.